# log4j not working in netbeans 7.0

Tags: log4j, netbeans-7, struts-1

I am new to log4j and learning it. I want to use it in a web application I am developing using the netbeans IDE 7.0 version( which in turn, is using Glassfish server)

I have instantiated and used a logger object in one of my action classes. I have put the log4j.properties file under WEB-INF, along with web.xml and struts-config.xml

Now when I run the application, I get the following error:
**SEVERE: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.struts.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl).
SEVERE: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
SEVERE: log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.**

I did some searching, and it seems this error is because my log4j.properties file is not being found. I saw several posts where it says that the properties file needs to be put in the classpath. I guess that would mean the WEB-INF/classes folder. But where do I put it, if I want to add the properties file directly **through Netbeans**?
Also, is it possible that there is some error in my log4j.properties file which is causing it to be not found? This is what I have in my properties file:

```
# configuring the root logger

log4j.rootlogger = DEBUG,FILE

# path of the logs folder

log = /logs


# configuring the file appender

log4j.appender.FILE = org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File = $(log)/test.log


# defining layout for the FileAppender

log4j.appender.File.Layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.File.Layout.conversionPattern = %m%n
```

Finally, if I have a properties file defined as above, do I still need to use 
    PropertyConfigurator.configure()
in the class where I have used logging?

I'm at my wits end trying to find out why this isnt working. Any suggestion or solution will be really helpful.